# Bind & Configure SSL Certificate in Jfrog Artifactory?

Tags: web, tomcat, apache2, artifactory

How to Bind & Configure SSL Certificate in Jfrog Artifactory? Do we need to Update in Tomcat or Apache2 Webserver?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Artifactory behind a web server line Nginx, Apache or others, just need to follow their guides for setting up TLS.

They can offload TLS and continue to Artifactory without TLS.

If need to setup TLS on Artifactory itself, you can follow [this KB with details](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-enable-tls-within-the-jfrog-platform/).

Comment: is there any other guideline available?

Comment: What is the requirement? What problems are you trying to solve?